# What is the best way to share files between Xen VM's?

Tags: xen, file-sharing

Is there some built-in way to share files between Xen guests?  I don't currently need to share the actual images, just some data files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean between Xen and the host or between different guests?

If guests, I don't think there is something provided but you should probably use NFS as it is the best supported file system that supports a decent number of permissions and attributes but assumes a trusted network.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [glusterfs](http://www.gluster.org/docs/index.php/Main_Page) or [lustre](http://wiki.lustre.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) to share files between Xen guests.

Comment: That's like saying you can use a USB key to share files between Xen guests.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and my solution was to add an extra virtual drive to each guest which pointed to a shared lvm or device.

So `xvda3` was pointed at `/dev/md0` in the guest configuration file. You could just as easily use `/dev/vg0/lg0` for an logical volume.